# Can't find main.dart as entrypoint, how to connect Android project to the main.dart file?

Tags: android, flutter, android-productflavors

Please don't mark as a duplicate. I have tried to read this [Flutter : Target file "lib/main.dart" not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50522153/flutter-target-file-lib-main-dart-not-found) but I have found no answer, because what I ask will be little different

so I have this error when I run my Flutter App through the Android project (from Android Studio), I mean for some reason I did not run the project through the Flutter project (not from VS Code). I have no issue If run my Flutter app through VS Code

this is the error

> Error: Error when reading 'lib/main.dart': No such file or directory
> import 'package:mobile/main.dart' as entrypoint

so basically the Android Studio can't find the `main.dart`.

I implement Flavor on my Flutter, so I have several main functions such as `main_production.dart`, `main_staging.dart` and `main_development.dart` instead of  normal `main.dart` . thats why the system can't find the entry point.

In iOS Xcode, I can set the main entry point through Flutter Target like this

[image]

but now I am confused, how to connect my Android project to the several main function (my dart files)

Answer (score 1):

In android studio, open action menu with (`cmd+shift+a` on mac and `ctrl+shift+a` on windows/linux) and select `Edit configurations`

[image]

Then, using a plus sign at the top, add a new flutter run config

[image]

And specify an appropriate entrypoint and flavor:

[image]

All that's left is to run the new config using either of the green buttons at the top (run or debug)

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I am really sorry, this is not what I am looking for. as I said, I have no issue if I run the app in VSCode. but for some reason now I need to run only the Android project only, not the flutter project

Comment: Sorry for not paying enough attention, I've changed my answer - please have a look if it's what you need